# English sentences to first order logic

Tags: discrete-mathematics, logic

I'm pretty new to first order logic and I'm attempting to translate some english sentences to first order logic.  Am I doing these correctly and if not can someone show me a correct way to represent the sentence?

**You cannot chase something that chases you.**

∀x∀y Chase(x,y) -> ¬Chase(y,x)

**If you growl at an animal and are small, the animal will chase you.**

∀x∀y Animal(y) ^ Growl_at(x,y) ^ Small(x) -> Chase(y,x)

**Any dog who sees something he hates, growls at it.**

∀x∀y Dog(x) ^ Hate(x,y) -> Growls_at(x,y)

**Cosmo is a small dog, and he hates all turkeys.**

∀x Small_dog(Cosmo) ^ Turkey(x) -> Hates(Cosmo,x)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They all look great! I would improve your third translation as follows:
$$
\forall x \, \forall y \, [\textsf{Dog}(x) \land \textsf{Sees}(x, y) \land \textsf{Hates}(x,y) \to \textsf{GrowlsAt}(x,y)]
$$

Comment: Isn't there an issue with the final one? Where is "Cosmo" defined? Everything inside should be an element. So we need to say $\exists y (Cosmo(y))$ somewhere along the way.

Comment: @vasshu Could you show me how you would write the final one?

Answer (score 1):

For the final one I would write something like...

$\exists x[(Cosmo(x) \land Small\_Dog(x) \land (\forall y(Turkey(y) \rightarrow Hates(x, y)))]$